# Powerquery extract text and numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have 3 columns :
*Id,Name,Email*

in the ID column i have values like :

123abcd,

_ETABCV,

34 dddd

I want, if possible, two new columns called "ID number" and "ID Text" where the first have only the numbers of the ID column, and the other only text of the ID column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In M, to grab numbers, add column ... custom column ... with formula

```
= Text.Select([NameOfYourColumnHere],{"0".."9",".","-"})
```

To grab letters, add column, custom column with

```
= Text.Select([NameOfYourColumnHere],{"a".."z","A".."Z"})
```

Comment: Thx for you answer but it gave me the following error : power bi sorry we couldn't convert a type record to text

Comment: Thats the thing the cells are not underlined, they are just "texts"

Comment: No worries thank you a lot found the problem it was some cleaning and tranforming mistakes, thank you a lot